# Can Firebase Firestore hold a dictionary where entries belong to a custom type with enums?

Tags: swift, enums, google-cloud-firestore

When storing a custom type in Firestore, I get this: *Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported type: __SwiftValue*.

```swift
struct Reply: Codable {
    var acceptance: Acceptance
    var date: Date

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case acceptance
        case date
    }
}

enum Acceptance: String, Codable {
    case Pending = "Pending"
    case Accepted = "Accepted"
    case Rejected = "Rejected"
}
```

These types are used to create a dictionary of the form

```swift
var replies =  [String: Reply]()
```

where the `String` key is used to associate a `userId` to a user `Reply`.

However when I try to store the `replies` variable as a field of a Firestore document, I get that exception.

```swift
db.collection("SomeCollection").addDocument(data: ["Replies": replies]) {...}
```

Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently `Firebase Firestore` only supports specific data types such as:

- Array
- Boolean
- Floating Point Number

And many more types that you can look up on this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types). With that being said, `Reply` is a custom type that unfortunately will not be accepted by `Firebase`. My suggestion is to break down your custom types until you can use the Swift types (Array, String, Int) and reconstruct `Reply` by constructing `Acceptance` using `Strings` that were previously saved to `Firebase`.

Comment: Actually, I tried to shape `Reply` as shown [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data?authuser=0), but then I thought that it failed because of the `enum` within the `struct`. So I ended to code/decode manually the entry as you suggest. For the enum I used the `.rawvalue` accessor. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that you figured out a solution! Hope the project is going well.

Comment: What about the Reference type? Why we can't use that for storing the reference to other document?

Comment: Can you elaborate further about a "Reference" type?

Answer (score 0):

along with [Miguel Tepale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63497869/8351061), check for nil values. If your Dictionary or the data that you are assigning have null values, then that may occur this problem as it cannot decide its type.